# In Meteor, what is difference between this.error and throw new Meteor.Error in Meteor.publish?

Tags: meteor

In `Meteor.publish`, what is a difference between using `this.error` and simply throwing an `Meteor.Error`?

Answer (score 6):

`this.error` is only available inside the publish method. Per [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#publish_error):

> Stops this client's subscription, triggering a call on the client to the `onError` callback passed to `Meteor.subscribe`, if any. If error is not a `Meteor.Error`, it will be mapped to `Meteor.Error(500, "Internal server error")`.

Throwing a `Meteor.Error` would not stop the client's subscription, it would just terminate execution and raise the exception. So if you want to ensure Meteor will clean up after you and allow you to handle the error on the client when something unexpected happens, it's recommended to use `this.error` rather than throwing your own inside the publish method.

Answer (score 3):

It seems they are the same. In the source code:

```
try {
  var res = self._handler.apply(self, EJSON.clone(self._params));
} catch (e) {
  self.error(e);
  return;
}
```

So if there is an exception thrown, `error` is called anyway. `error` also stops the subscription.